# View word and pdf documents in browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, ms-word

Is there a easy way to view a word or pdf document in my webpage? I searched In google, but didn't find what i need...

I want it to load word or pdf document from link, and show the content of that document In the webpage.

Comment: you want to display doc/pdf in your whole webpage or in some part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the documents are not confidential, and you don't mind uploading it to a publicly avaliable website, you could embed the reader from [scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) .

They also have an [API](http://www.scribd.com/developers), which might allow you to restrict who can view your documents.

Comment: does it require to upload files to scridb first? I'd like to have documents on my webpage and just to load them from there.

Comment: Yes, the files will need to be uploaded to scribd first. You then embed their reader, much like how you would embed youtube videos. If you would like to use your own uploader (say in a CMS), you can use their [upload API](http://www.scribd.com/developers/api?method_name=docs.upload) to upload the documents without hitting their site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open pdf file from link in HTML than this code may help you:

`<a href=\"NAME OF FILE.pdf\" title=>NAME OF LINK AS YOU WANT IT TO APPEAR>Click Here</a>`

this link open your pdf file in the current web page.
For further information on this topic
-> [Click here](http://www.ehow.com/how_4451133_display-pdf-file-html-web.html)